# Eclipse - update / installing new software is incredibly slow

Tags: eclipse, updates

This problem has already been discribed before. But none of the suggested solutions work for me.

This is the problem:

I've got the latest version of Eclipse Luna (4.4.1) installed. If I want to do an update or install new software, it takes a very long time to complete (many HOURS). This is still the case if I download the desired software into a local archive/update site and install from there. But when I disable all network adapters and then install from such a "local" update site, the installation takes only a few seconds.

This "trick" to disable network adaptes can already be found as a proposed solution for the same question from 2010 here: [Eclipse online access extremely slow--cannot complete updates or install new software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435092/eclipse-online-access-extremely-slow-cannot-complete-updates-or-install-new-sof). The accepted answer for this question does not help. I already disabled the "Contact all update sites" option and also added "-Declipse.p2.mirrors=false" to my eclipse.ini.

The disable-network-adapters-trick is no acceptable solution. Because I may not comment (reputation) I have to re-open the question.

Answer (score 4):

I have been facing the same issue. One thing worked for me by disabling the **Available software sites** in **Preferences**.

1. Go to <kbd>Windows</kbd> → <kbd>Preferences</kbd>
2. Type in search ***available software sites***
3. Try unchecking the several sites which you do not want to look for
   updates.